# Win32 GDI: AlphaBlend() not using constant alpha value correctly

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

The code provided at the end draws a grid of red 3x3px rectangles with a random constant alpha value using `AlphaBlend()`. The output however, turns out not "quite" random:

[image: sample_output]

Notice runs of constant alpha along x-axis.

What might be causing this?

P.S. Stepping though the debugger produces the expected output.

---

Code to produce output:

```
void draw_mark(HDC hdc, int x, int y, 
               COLORREF mark_clr, int mark_w, int mark_h, BYTE alpha);

void produce_output(HWND hWnd) {
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    const int grid_w = 64, grid_h = 64;
    const int mark_sz = 3;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    for(int y = 0; y < grid_h; ++y) {
        for(int x = 0; x < grid_w; ++x) {
            BYTE rnd_alpha = rand();    // use random alpha for each mark
            draw_mark(hdc, x * mark_sz, y * mark_sz, 
                      RGB(255,0,0), mark_sz, mark_sz, rnd_alpha);
        }
    }

    // clean-up
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}

// draws a [mark_w x mark_h] rectangle at (x,y) with alpha
void draw_mark(HDC hdc, int x, int y, 
               COLORREF mark_clr, int mark_w, int mark_h, BYTE alpha) 
{
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HBITMAP hbm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, mark_w, mark_h);
    HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hdcMem, hbm);

    for(int x = 0; x < mark_w; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < mark_h; ++y) {
            SetPixel(hdcMem, x, y, mark_clr);
        }
    }
    POINT marker_center{mark_w / 2, mark_h / 2};
    SetPixel(hdcMem, marker_center.x, marker_center.y, RGB(255, 255, 255));

    BLENDFUNCTION bf{};
    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.AlphaFormat = 0;             // ignore source per-pixel alpha and...
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = alpha; // ...use constant alpha provided instead

    AlphaBlend(hdc, 
               x - marker_center.x, y - marker_center.y, 
               mark_w, mark_h,  
               hdcMem, 0, 0, mark_w, mark_h, bf);

    // clean-up
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hOldBmp);
    DeleteObject(hbm);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
};
```

---

*EDIT - As I look more into it, here are the additional issues I have noticed:*

1- Output is normal when `AlphaBlend()` destination is a memory DC, but not when a window DC. So the issue has to do with bliting directly to screen.

2- Corrupt output is unrelated to use of `rand()` function. Replacing `BYTE rnd_alpha = rand();` with `++alpha` also produces somewhat similar corrupt outputs.

3- More interestingly, suspending the thread in the **inner loop** such as `Sleep(some_duration)` seems to reduce the corruption. Higher the `some_duration`, less the corruption. Here is a sample output:

[image]

First output is generated by first blitting to a memory DC, then to window. The rest is directly to the window. Notice how corruption increases(i.e. output becomes less random) as thread suspension time decreases.

Comment: GDI is strictly 24bpp and does not support alpha.  AlphaBlend() was a hack to use a bitmap with transparency anyway, but the blend result is 24bpp.  This kind of code went out of style almost 20 years ago, please use gdiplus.h

Comment: If stepping through the debugger (as opposed to just letting it run as fast as it can) produces the desired result, then it sounds like you are constantly re-seeding the PNRG, using the current time. The debugger slows the code down enough so that re-seeding the PNRG happens at distinct times, whereas not running under a debugger happens to re-seed it with the same time value multiple times in a row.

Comment: @IInspectable : `rand()` used is the one in `cstdlib`, so I think seeding using time is not the issue.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : I tried logging generated alpha values just before `AlphaBlend()` call. Numbers look random enough.

Comment: I didn't see the earlier comment, I sort of repeated IInspectable. I tried the code on my computer and it looks random. `rand` sometimes goes wrong if the seed is wrong. Anyway, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: We don't know, if it is an issue or not. We can't see the code, where the PRNG is seeded. It is not an issue to seed the PRNG with the current time. It is an issue when doing it repeatedly. Are you?

Comment: @IInspectable : Poor wording on my part. I also assumed that you thought `rand()` is a non-standard function that seeds itself with time(which doesn't make much sense now that I think of it). What I meant is `rand()` is the standart library function AND it is not seeded *anywhere* in the code. I logged alpha values just before `AlphaBlend()` uses it. Values look random but output is not.

Comment: I can repro using your code sample but I don't have an explanation for the result.

Comment: @zett42 what compiler and OS do you use? Did you call `srand` once at the beginning?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani VS2017 under Win 10. Getting similar results whether or not I'm calling `srand` once at the beginning. Long runs of identical cells being output, in my case even longer runs than in OPs image. Fun thing, when I add `Sleep(1)` at the end of `draw_mark()`, I get a more random result.

Comment: The use of `rand()` really is not the cause here. I've set `alpha = y * 255 / grid_h` which should produce a gradient of 64 distinct color values. Though I only get 10 different values in [the output](https://imgur.com/a/TFbcI). Again, when inserting a `Sleep` in the outer loop, I get the expected result.

Comment: This is getting confusing now. There are two separate issues about `rand` and `AlphaBlend` which need to be separated. If `AlphaBlend` misbehaves it should do it with some consistency, separate from `rand`. Btw, I am using VS2015/Win10.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. Output seems to be reasonable random. The only little problem is that starting drawing at top left corner of the window will leave first row and column cropped by one pixel. However this can be easily fixed by adjusting point coordinates when calling `AlphaBlend` `x + 1 - marker_center.x, y + 1 - marker_center.y,`

Comment: @zett42 : It seems higher the thread suspension time, less the corruption. I edited OP with a demo. Also, I get normal output when I first blit to mem DC, and then to window. Corruption occurs only when blitting to window.

Comment: @VTT : You should blit directly to window to get corrupt output. If you blit to memory DC, output is normal.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Are you blitting directly to window, or first to a memory DC, then to window? Please see the edit to OP.

Comment: The only modification I made is to call `produce_output` drawing body part inside of `WM_PAINT` handler, that is using dc returned by `BeginPaint` instead of the one returned by `GetDC` (which should be the same actually). I guess you should supply complete code snippet, including window initialization and message loop.

Comment: @VTT : I get the same corrupt output when used that way as well. Window setup uses the default when a new Win32 project is created in VS2017. I use `WM_LBUTTONDOWN:{ produce_output(hWnd); break; }` for output.